# Can KeyboardState detect an incorrect key?

Tags: c#, keyboard, state, monogame

I'm making a game in C# and MonoGame that needs to detect when specific keys are pressed. I've created a controller class which detects shift key presses (the button that makes the player shoot bullets) in the following way.

```
public class Controller
{
    KeyboardState keyboardState;

    public Controller()
    {
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        keyboardState = Keyboard.GetState(); //Get a new controller state
    }

    public bool RightShootButton
    {
        get
        {
            return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift); //Shoot a bullet to the right if right shift is pressed
        }
    }

    public bool LeftShootButton
    {
        get
        {
            return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift); //Shoot a bullet to the left if left shift is pressed
        }
    }
}
```

The RightShootButton property works fine, but the LeftShootButton has a strange glitch. The player shoots a bullet to the left when any of the arrow keys (up, down, left or right) are pressed, even though I am not asking for those key presses. Is it possible for the KeyboardState to detect a key press incorrectly, or is there most likely a bug in my code that I've missed? If it's the former, is there any way to fix this problem?

Edit:

Here's some more code to show how things work. Bullets are created like this in the Player class. This is the only part of the code where bullets are created (they are added to a list).

```
if (controller.RightShootButton)
{
    level.Bullets.Add(new Bullet(playerPosition, true)); //These parameters define where the bullet is and whether it travels left or right
}
else if (controller.LeftShootButton)
{
    level.Bullets.Add(new Bullet(playerPosition, false));
}
```

The player moves left and right with this code. Again, this is the only part of the code that involves movement.

```
if (controller.RightButton || controller.LeftButton)
{
    if (controller.RightButton && playerPosition.X < level.End)
    {
        playerPosition.X += 2; //Move right if the player hasn't reached the side of the screen (the level.End value)
    }

    if (controller.LeftButton && playerPosition.X > 0)
    {
        playerPosition.X -= 2; //Move left if not at the side of the screen
    }
}
```

Finally, these are the properties that detect arrow key presses in the controller class. These currently have gamepad functionality, but the shooting properties don't.

```
public bool UpButton
{
    get
    {
        return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || gamepadState.DPad.Up == ButtonState.Pressed || gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y > 0.0f;
    }
}

public bool DownButton
{
    get
    {
        return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || gamepadState.DPad.Down == ButtonState.Pressed || gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y < 0.0f;
    }
}

public bool LeftButton
{
    get
    {
        return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || gamepadState.DPad.Left == ButtonState.Pressed || gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X < 0.0f;
    }
}

public bool RightButton
{
    get
    {
        return keyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || gamepadState.DPad.Right == ButtonState.Pressed || gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X > 0.0f;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like something else is going on.  How do you move your character left and right?

Comment: It has to be something that's not in your code right here... try looking for *anything* to do with input/keyboard in your code.

Comment: Also, whats your shoot code?

Comment: I don't see any code that tests the state of the arrow keys. Since the keyboard state behaves as a modifier of a key, it seems to me that your program needs to test all other keys that might also be pressed, and take appropriate action. Since this kind of testing probably needs to happen in lots of other places, it seems to me that you should develop a generic, data driven keyboard event processor that dispatches valid events to other routines. For example, this is how the main window procedure of a standard Windows program (written in C or C++, with or without support from MFC works.

Comment: I've added more code to show what's going on with movement and shooting.

Comment: I think I've found some more information about the problem. The game project was created in Visual Studio 2013 as a "MonoGame Windows Project" for the Windows desktop with DirectX. I created a new game using the same project type and the same bug occurred (The arrow keys are mistaken for left shift). I created a new "MonoGame Windows OpenGl Project" and the same glitch did not occur. It seems that the project type was the problem.